# How to convert XML file to a Database?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, database, data-dump

I recently downloaded the SO Data Dump and was wondering how I could convert it from XML to a DB that I could use in my .NET applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [wiki article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100304111946/http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/How_to_Import_the_StackOverflow_XML_into_SQL_Server) describing the process of converting the XML data dump to a database by using stored procedures.

[SQLServerPedia site](http://sqlserverpedia.com/) contains many other articles related to SO -

- [Understanding the StackOverflow Database Schema](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema)
- [Interesting StackOverflow Database Queries](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Interesting_StackOverflow_Database_Queries), etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [XML Bulk Load](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005).

Answer (score 2):

you can convert it to DataSet using [DataSet.ReadXml Method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311566) and that insert datatables to database

Answer (score 1):

C# handles XML natively very well.  Unless there is a large amount of XML, simply use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

If you have large amounts of XML, then handling it in streaming mode is proably less work than putting it in a DB

Answer (score 1):

Hm, just use a XML parser, and make the database schema as you wish...you can also map the xml to a database directly...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database
Do some more reading...really..